# Excel How to concatenate cells using hierarchy and indent

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, concatenation

I received a task. Names and data has been changed. I received a Excel sheet with goods values, ident, description. Goal is to make description with using this tree data sources.

I would like to concatenate descriptions based on ident and hierarchy as shown below.

[Excel example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15V1s.png)

I think something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQtufvRUbaI&t=314s&ab_channel=SixMinutes.Smarter.

My problem is, I don't know how to make rule that changes when indent amount goes up?

All help and ideas are appreciated!